# Wordpress Error message after upgrade to PHP 7.2

Tags: php, wordpress

We've updated our wordpress site to PHP 7.2 and it's throwing up the following errors:

> Warning: Declaration of Portfolio_Walker::start_el(&$output,
>   $category, $depth, $args) should be compatible with
>   Walker_Category::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args =
>   Array, $id = 0) in
>   /home/rapidmet/public_html/wp-content/themes/rapidmetals/functions.php
>   on line 0
>
> Warning: Declaration of My_Walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth,
>   $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output,
>   $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in
>   /home/rapidmet/public_html/wp-content/themes/rapidmetals/functions.php
>   on line 0

would anyone know how to stop these errors occuring?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried to solve this by yourself? Please also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Contact your theme maker, they may have a workaround, if you're not familiar with PHP.

Comment: Contact the theme developer, or check if there's no theme update, also check if you have the latest Wordpress instalation

Comment: The start_el method declaration of your custom walker needs to match that of the Walker_Nav_Menu class, in terms of what parameters it takes. You could fix this yourself by modifying it in functions.php of the theme - but that will likely be overwritten the next time you update your theme. Since these are warnings only, and do not cause actual functional errors, you better just make PHP not show warnings to begin with - that (not showing errors in the front-end) is the recommended setup for production websites anyway.

Comment: Or is this your own theme, not from a 3rd-party vendor? (Theme name from the path shown above matches the company name on your profile, so …) In that case, just find the lines that declare `Portfolio_Walker::start_el` and  `My_Walker::start_el` in your functions.php, and overwrite the list of parameters with those of the “originals”.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I apologise if I didn't follow the forum rules, I was under a bit of pressure to get the warning message gone. We edited the PHP file to stop showing warning as suggested by @misorude.